# Sinatra Double Request Issue

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

I'm witnessing an issue where a `Sinatra` page is loading twice.  I have a `session` secret string that's generated and output to the console `error.log` which is where I'm finding it's happening twice.

```
get '/contact' do
  puts '/get contact'
  grab = Dev.make_randomsecret
  puts "grab: #{ grab }"
  session[:contactsecret] = grab
  @contactsecret = grab                     # this is for an erb view
  puts "get /contact with secret #{ session[:contactsecret] }"
end

post "/contact_receive" do
  @title = "Contact the Strategy Brewhouse"
  puts "arrival post /contact with #{ session[:contactsecret] } | host: #{ request.host.to_s }"
  puts "session: #{ session[:contactsecret] } | params cs: #{ params[:cs] } (equal: #{ params[:cs] == session[:contactsecret] })"
  session[:contactsecret] = nil
  
  [email stuff]

  erb :submit
end
```

The log shows two requests of `/contact`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2023:13:25:53 -0500] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 2440 "http://compshort.local/contact" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2023:13:26:00 -0500] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 2440 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

The console `error.log` shows two replies:

```
App 47140 output: /get contact
App 47140 output: grab: NQS
App 47140 output: get /contact with secret NQS
App 47140 output: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2023:13:25:53 -0500] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 2440 1.0823
App 47140 output: /get contact
App 47140 output: grab: HUQ
App 47140 output: get /contact with secret HUQ
App 47140 output: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2023:13:26:00 -0500] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 2440 1.0597
```

As this log shows, two replies with two independently generated secrets.  That second request/reply is what's confusing.  I have no clue why it's there.  There are no refresh instructions anywhere in my app.  This happens when `/tmp/always_restart.txt` is present (meaning the app compiles before every request) and when it's marked `/tmp/Xalways_restart.txt`, which compiles first run only.  Multiple requests done manually in either condition, has the same result.

I'm thinking this is a `Sinatra` thing, even if I have something set wrong.  That second request in the `access.log` has me confused as the request is for "-".  Even on my home/landing page, I am seeing the same double request happening.

This was happenign with another `development` site on the same box, using the same setup, then it went away.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running HTTPS? How long does it take for the server to respond to the browser when the request is initiated?

Comment: No.  Even with internal `HTTP` links, it's loading twice.  `nginx.conf` only has `listen port 80;'.  But the request happens, then a delay of a second or two, then the second request (no referrer) happens.

Comment: There is a thing with Chrome (since they went HTTPS by default) that it first tries HTTPS and if the response takes more than 3 seconds it falls back to HTTP. It can be seen in inspect as a cancelled request. But I don't think this would be it since you dont listen on 443.

Comment: Bingo!  Firefox works.  So for Chrome to work anywhere, it all has to be HTTPS?

Comment: It does not have to be HTTPS but unless `http://` is explicitly given it tries HTTPS first then HTTP.

Comment: Ya I'm using relative paths for links, because that takes care of the `localhost` __.local__ domain.  But I can take care of that.  Good to know.

Comment: Moved to port 443, and all my links are full path now, pointing to `https` only.  It's still happening.

Comment: It still can happen. Chrome can even downgrade HTTPS to HTTP if it takes more than 3 seconds to load (I think this is evil). You cannot fix this. You should do your best to return the response as fast as possible. 3 seconds is quite a long time and the user should not be waiting for so long. Worst case scenario your Chrome users will wait 3 extra seconds for long running requests.

Comment: That's just amazing.  What a colossal problem.  Looks like I will have to manually enter those `localhost` `vhosts` into `Chrome`.  Cheers

Comment: Well, deleted those localhost domains, and it's still behaving this way.  Disabled `always_restart.txt` and it's responding before 3 seconds, and successful, as reported in the log.  But a second `session_secret` still being created as it's loading http.  Any suggestions?  I can't guarantee 3 seconds.  This is on my localhost and it's behaving this way.

Comment: Do you see any `Sinatra` solutions to this?

Comment: Generally an application should be designed in a way that repeated GET requests do not matter. I don't have enough insight to you application, maybe do not create new `session[:contactsecret]` when there already is one?

Comment: Just providing a security key for a form, in order to avoid spam.  I don't want to implement a `captcha`.